# Remove all tables from schema except specific ones in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema

I have a SQL database and I would like to remove almost all tables related to a specific schema except a couple of them. Therefore I think I would need to edit the following sql query (which removes all tables of a specific schema):

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable
@command1 = 'DROP TABLE ?'
, @whereand = 'AND SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = ''your_schema_name'' '
```

Would you be able to suggest a smart and elegant way so that I can add a list of tables that I would like to keep and remove everything else?

Comment: How often do you intend to do this?

Comment: Well in theory an indefinite number of times... it could be once a week or several times a day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep using `sp_msforeachtable`, pass in the set of tables names to keep using a temp table. Here's an example using the `boo` schema:

```sql
create schema boo;
create table boo.t(i int);

create table #keep (name sysname); 
insert #keep values ('myFirsttable'), ('mySecondTable'), ('myThirdTable');

exec sp_msforeachtable 
   @command1='drop table ?; print ''dropped ?''',
   @whereand = 'and schema_name(schema_id) = ''your_schema_name'' and object_name(object_id) not in (select name from #keep)';
```

But personally, I'd probably just write my own stored procedure with a cursor. It's harder to mess up.

Note that this solution expects you to put the tables you want to *keep* into the temp table. Charlieface's solution expects you to put the names of tables you want to *drop* into the table variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It appears to me that I can insert the name of one table. What if I have more than one? Can I do something like this: insert #keep select 'mytable1', 'mytable2;

Comment: Just insert multiple rows into `#keep`, yeah. Although the syntax you have there wouldn't work. Instead use...`create table #keep (name sysname);
insert #keep values ('mytable'), ('mySecondTable'), ('myThirdTable') --, etc`

Comment: I updated your answer, is it correct now?

Comment: Yep, that would be the syntax.

Comment: Note that this is fairly dangerous, for example, what if you make a typo when putting the table names to keep into the `#keep` table? Then you could drop a table you didn't intend to drop! So, you know, do this in a transaction (I added a print statement so it outputs all the tables that are dropped)

Answer (score 1):

You could place a list of tables you want to delete stored in a table variable or Table-Valued Parameter `@tables` then you can simply execute dynamic SQL with it.

```
DECLARE @tables TABLE (tablename sysname);
INSERT @tables (tablename)
SELECT t.name
FROM sys.tables t
WHERE t.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('your_schema_name');

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) =
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(
        'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME('your_schema_name') + '.' + QUOTENAME(tablename) + ';'
      AS nvarchar(max)), '
'   )
    FROM @tables
);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Alternatively, select it directly from `sys.tables`

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) =
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(
        'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ';'
      AS nvarchar(max)), '
'   )
    FROM sys.tables t
    WHERE t.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('your_schema_name')
);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So just to make it clear since I am not so expert. Where should I place the list of tables? Here? TABLE (my_tables_name sysname)

And what is sysname? Should I replace it with something else?

Comment: `sysname` is just an alias for `nvarchar(128)`. Depends how you want to get the list of tables. Will you pass them in through a parameter, or do some complex search? Then insert them into `@tables` as shown. Or you could do `INSERT @tables (tablename) VALUES ('table1'),('table2');` If it's just a simple filter on schema, then you can do the second version instead.